# Gradle sync error failed to find : com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.+'

Tags: android, android-studio, admob, google-play-services, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to set `AdMob` to my application, but when I try to sync my  project this error shows up:

[image]

I have already downloaded Google Play Services and I don't know how to fix this error. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a dot there. Here's how it should look like:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.+'
```

Also using + sign to account for other versions is discouraged, you should use the exact version, like:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.71'
```

Comment: Thank you! However i copied that from developer.android setup , i don't know why they didn't write 6.1.11 instead of 6.1.+ , however thank you again!

Comment: Understandable to write 6.1.+ in websites, to account for future changes. In your own code you should use constant numbers because once the versions change you will be notified and will simply update it.

Comment: @user3249477 Thanks for explanation. I just wanted to ask you why should we not use + when I see such habit even on official blogs.

Answer (score 5):

For me I had to update the google repository to Rev. 13 and the IDE informed me right away the newer play-services version that's available i.e (in my case) 6.1.71